# How much force can a concrete block fence and wood stud hold when installing a large shade sail?

Tags: concrete, wood, screws, anchor, wind

I have a standard concrete block fence. I want to install a large 20 x 26 foot shade sail, or two 20 x 13 shade sails by screwing hooks into the wall, and the other end into my house via the studs.

1. will this rip out of the concrete?
2. will this rip out of my house?

What is the calculation for knowing the maximum force that concrete blocks, and wood housing studs, can hold?

Comment: you did not describe the anchor points, so the answers are `maybe and maybe`

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. @jsotola gave you the most precise answer we can; if you want better, you'll need to give us a lot more information.

Comment: The concrete block fence is a standard us block. So the anchor point would be directly into the block. As far as the house, I can use a stud or the wood beam at the edge of the roof. But I don't know where to anchor really,  that's why I'm here asking for the best anchor points and how strong they are. Thanks.

Comment: I'll get a photo to help describe it

Comment: @TetraDev , Did you ever figure this out? I'm curious, too. I think there are some installation instructions that mention 100lbs tension on anchors, and then suggest additional expected based on sqft of shade. Assuming you figure out expected load on the anchors, this sort of boils down to asking how much torque (sideways pull at what height) such dividing walls can safely take. For mine, I thought I might just do it and then remove it if I see localized damage forming (and switch to a dedicated post). I'm interested in anyone's answer... Thanks!